# Pyspark general import problems

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, installation, path

I succesfully instaled Spark and Pyspark in my machine, added path variables, etc. but keeps facing import problems.

This is the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .config("spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
                    .config("spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
                    .enableHiveSupport() \
                    .getOrCreate()
```

And this is the error message:

```
"C:\...\Desktop\Clube\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:.../Desktop/Clube/services/ce_modelo_analise.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Desktop\Clube\services\ce_modelo_analise.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyspark import accumulators
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\accumulators.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pyspark.serializers import read_int, PickleSerializer
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 71, in <module>
    from pyspark import cloudpickle
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 145, in <module>
    _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 126, in _make_cell_set_template_code
    return types.CodeType(

TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

If I remove the import line, those problems disappear. As I said before, my path variables are set:

[image]

and

[image]

Also, Spark is running correctly in cmd:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going deeper I found the problem: I'm using Spark in version 2.4, which works with Python 3.7 tops.

As I was using Python 3.10, the problem was happening.

So if you're experiencing the same kind of issue, try to change your versions.